# Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed

Tags: android, channel

I am creating a customer registration page which adds a customer to my firebase database. Once registered the app should move onto the next activity which is a google map. The customer is added to the databse but crashes when moving onto the next activity. Here is my code:

SignupActivityCustomer.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class SignupActivityCustomer extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextName, editTextEmail, editTextPassword, editTextPhone;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private static final String TAG = "SignupActivityCustomer";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_customer);

        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_email);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
        editTextPhone = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_phone);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        findViewById(R.id.button_register).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            //handle the already login user
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        final String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString().trim();

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            editTextName.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_name));
            editTextName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            editTextEmail.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_email));
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            editTextEmail.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_email_invalid));
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPassword.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_password));
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6) {
            editTextPassword.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_password_length));
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (phone.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPhone.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_phone));
            editTextPhone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (phone.length() != 10) {
            editTextPhone.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_phone_invalid));
            editTextPhone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }


        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "adding customer");
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Customer user = new Customer(
                                    name,
                                    email,
                                    phone
                            );

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customers")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "customer added");
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivityCustomer.this, CustomerHome.class));
                                    } else {
                                        //display a failure message
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivityCustomer.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_register:
                registerUser();
                break;
        }
    }
}

Logcat error:

2019-01-26 11:29:10.843 4038-4038/com.example.julie.fyp D/SignupActivityCustomer: customer added
2019-01-26 11:29:11.669 1880-1959/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '4a251a2 com.example.julie.fyp/com.example.julie.fyp.SignupActivityCustomer (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2019-01-26 11:29:11.669 1880-1959/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '4a251a2 com.example.julie.fyp/com.example.julie.fyp.SignupActivityCustomer (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-01-26 11:29:11.719 1880-2523/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4a251a2 com.example.julie.fyp/com.example.julie.fyp.SignupActivityCustomer (server)'
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, Firebase works asynchronous now, therefore it's working on another thread.

you can try putting `startActivity` in `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` code

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivityCustomer.this, CustomerHome.class));
        }
    });
} else {
    //display a failure message
}
```

hope it works